# get the position of a recyclerview item when I click on an imagebutton

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

here is the method I use to get the position of a recyclerview items and perform an accurate action with:

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {

}
```

I put imagebutton in the file that inflates my recyclerview as shown in this picture:
[image]

my imagesbutton are in the activity that plays the video as shown in this picture.
[![image]
here is my Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Data> data= Collections.emptyList();
Data current;
private int currentPos=0;

// create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
public Adapter(Context context, List<Data> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Obtenir la position actuelle de l'élément dans recyclerview pour lier les données et affecter des valeurs à partir de la liste
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    Data current = data.get(position);

    myHolder.textFishName.setText(current.catName);
    myHolder.textSize.setText(current.sizeName);
    myHolder.textSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    myHolder.textType.setText(current.fishName);
    myHolder.id.setText(""+current.idServer+"");
    myHolder.textPrice.setText("" + current.price + "");
    myHolder.textPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

    // load image into imageview using glide
    Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.43.196/vibe2/images/" + current.fishImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
            .into(myHolder.ivFish);
}

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textFishName;
    ImageView ivFish;
    TextView textSize;
    TextView textType;
    TextView textPrice;
    TextView counter;
    TextView id;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textFishName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
        ivFish = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFish);
        textSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSize);
        textType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
        textPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        counter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove any click listeners from the ImageView and the RecyclerView item should consume the click action. Or do you want to do something else with the ImageView?

Comment: yes I want to do another action with the imagebutton

Comment: Can you show where is your imageButton in the above screenshot?

Comment: i updated my question. check please!

Answer (score 1):

This can be archived by using an interface from activity to RecyclerView's ViewHolder. In ViewHolder you can implement onClickListener in which you can pass the click even and your required information from ViewHolder as well.

```
    public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Data> data= Collections.emptyList();
    Data current;
    private int currentPos=0;
    // Custom listener to relay to selected data from ViewHolder to Activity
    private AdapterListener adapterListener;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public Adapter(Context context, List<Data> data, AdapterListener adapterListener){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
        this.adapterListener = adapterListener;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view, adapterListener);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        // Obtenir la position actuelle de l'élément dans recyclerview pour lier les données et affecter des valeurs à partir de la liste
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        myHolder.setData(data.get(position));


    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textFishName;
    ImageView ivFish;
    TextView textSize;
    TextView textType;
    TextView textPrice;
    TextView counter;
    TextView id;
    Data data;

    // Adapter listener
    private AdapterListener adapterListener;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView, AdapterListener adapterListener) {
        super(itemView);
        textFishName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
        ivFish = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFish);
        textSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSize);
        textType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
        textPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        counter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        this.adapterListener = adapterListener;
    }

    public void setData(Data data){
        this.data = data;
        textFishName.setText(current.catName);
        textSize.setText(current.sizeName);
        textSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textType.setText(current.fishName);
        id.setText(""+current.idServer+"");
        textPrice.setText("" + current.price + "");
        textPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.43.196/vibe2/images/" + current.fishImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .into(ivFish);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.ivFish:
                adapterListener.onClickImageView(getAdapterPosition(), data);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public interface AdapterListener {
    void onClickImageView(int position, Data data);
}
```

At last implement the interface AdapterListener in the class where you creating Adapter.

Comment: Your code is pretty fuzzy can you correct mine so I can get the same result please?

Comment: I have changed the code as per your classes. @Anubis

Comment: Tell me please it works too if I'm in another activity? Because I have an activity that contains a videoview, when the user clicks on an element of the recyclerview, it launches the video in this view and I would like that the user can have the possibility to download or to like the video while he looks at her!

Comment: @anubis This feature is not possible only with this codesnippet. It involves more than a viewholder delegations. Would you please ask this as a separate question so that we can have a separate thread to discuss this out.

Comment: alright I will rephrase with another question and what I have to try

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
make interface into adapter class and handle the click event like below code..

```
    OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(int pos); //pass any things
}
```

then after..

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    String data = mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(position);
        }
    });
}
```

after that in activity adapter bind into listview or recycler view then after call below code it means adaper not null..

```
       adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click Item Postion::"+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this inside your `ViewHolder` and not in the `onBindViewHolder` since it's called every time the item is redrawn.

```
...
// create constructor to get widget reference
public MyHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ...
    ivFish = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFish);
    ...

    ivFish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(getAdapterPosition() != -1) { // Avoid Exception
                // use getAdapterPosition() to get the current position             
            }                
        }
    });
}
```

You can furthermore pass a interface to your RecyclerView Adapter, call this interface inside the ClickListener and perform the desired action inside your Fragment/Activity.